# How to force WebBrowser control to select one specific client certificate?

Tags: .net, certificate, webbrowser-control, x509certificate

Anyone knows how to force the WebBrowser control to automatically select a specific client certificate and not open the pop up with client certificates list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue changing the certificate purposes to "Disable all purposes for this certificate", so just the certificate with the desired purpose could be used by WebBrowser control.