# How can you specify which certificate is presented from the WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I have a webbrowser control embedded in a WinForms app that's loading content which requires a digitial certificate. If there is only one valid certificate in my certificates collection, it works OK.

However, if I have more than one cert, particularly if one of them is invalid, the wrong cert seems to be selected and submitted. When the app get distributed, I have no idea what certs they'll have installed.

Is there any way, besides [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388149/how-to-force-webbrowser-control-to-select-one-specific-client-certificate), to ensure the WebBrowser control will select the right certificate?

Comment: For what operation is your certificate chosen? Is it client-side authentication or ... ?

Comment: Yes, authentication. We issue the users with a certificate, then require that certificate, and a user name and password, to login and use our services. It's simple when using WebRequest, because you can just attach the right certificate...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?